# How to draw on top of WPF effects in data grid control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, effects

I have a data grid control where I am using a custom effect called FastShadow which is like a glow.

I want the effect to glow outside its bounds, so that's fine but when I draw another shape on top, I don't want this shape to be affected. In this case, it's the Green/Blue Rectangle shapes.

As you can see these rectangle shapes get discolored by the glow effect. The ones without the glow effect behind them looks fine.

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="myMainWindow"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Profit Tracker"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Topmost="True"
    Height="426">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#1e90ff"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>



        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF" />
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2eff00" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />-->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />-->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>-->
                </Trigger>



                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="4"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#006400" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#75001D" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Coins}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="MyKey" />

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ViewScale, ElementName=myMainWindow}" ScaleY="{Binding ViewScale, ElementName=myMainWindow}" />
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>

        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" MaxWidth="40">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid>
                            <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}">

                                <Border Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Background="#ffff00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="7">
                                    <local:FastShadow Color="Yellow" ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" BlurRadius="80" Opacity="0.2">
                                    </local:FastShadow>
                                </Border>

                                <Border Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Background="#ffff00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="7">
                                    <local:FastShadow Color="#ff8d0a" ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" BlurRadius="80" Opacity="0.4">
                                    </local:FastShadow>
                                </Border>

                                <Border BorderBrush="#ff8d0a" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Background="#ffff00">
                                    <Border Margin="1" BorderBrush="#fff533" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="3" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Border.Effect>
                                            <BlurEffect Radius="50"/>
                                        </Border.Effect>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>

                                <Grid Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <Grid Background="GreenYellow">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="DarkGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50">
                                        </Rectangle>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid >
                                        <Rectangle Fill="DarkBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20">
                                        </Rectangle>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>
                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="24">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Ellipse Width="8" Height="8" Fill="Blue" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>



                <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="60"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void SetField<T> ( ref T field, T value, string propertyName )
        {
            if ( !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals ( field, value ) )
            {
                field = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke ( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propertyName ) );
            }
        }


        decimal viewScale = 1;
        public decimal ViewScale
        {
            get => this.viewScale;
            set => SetField ( ref this.viewScale, value,
                "ViewScale"
                );
        }

        ObservableCollection<Coin> _coins;
        public ObservableCollection<Coin> Coins { get => _coins; set => SetField ( ref _coins, value, nameof ( _coins ) ); }
        public ICollectionView CollectionView;

        public MainWindow ( )
        {
            this.Coins = new ObservableCollection<Coin> ( );
            for ( int i = 0; i < 25; ++i )
                this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 1", i ) );

            this.Coins [ 1 ].IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            this.Coins [ 4 ].IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            this.Coins [ 7 ].IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;

            this.DataContext = this;

            InitializeComponent ( );

            this.PreviewKeyDown += MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown;
            this.MouseLeftButtonDown += MainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        }

        private void MainWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown ( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( ( Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt ) == ModifierKeys.Alt )
                DragMove ( );
        }

        void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown ( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( e.Key == Key.Home )
            {
                this.dataGrid.ScrollIntoView ( this.dataGrid.Items [ 0 ] );
            }
            if ( e.Key == Key.End )
            {
                this.dataGrid.ScrollIntoView ( this.dataGrid.Items [ this.dataGrid.Items.Count - 1 ] );
                this.dataGrid.UpdateLayout ( );
                this.dataGrid.ScrollIntoView ( this.dataGrid.Items [ 0 ] );
            }
            else if ( e.Key == Key.F12 )
            {
                this.ViewScale += 0.1m;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Coin
    {
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public int PNL { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush Color2 { get; set; }

        public Visibility IsVisible { get; set; }

        public Coin ( string symbol, int pnl )
        {
            this.Symbol = symbol;
            this.PNL = pnl;

            Random rnd = new Random ( );
            Color c = Color.FromRgb ( ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ) );

            this.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush ( c );

            this.IsVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

**class FastShadow**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Emulates the System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowEffect using
    /// rectangles and gradients, which performs a million times better
    /// and won't randomly crash a good percentage of your end-user's 
    /// video drivers.
    /// </summary>
    public class FastShadow : Decorator
    {

        #region Dynamic Properties

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register (
                        "Color",
                        typeof ( Color ),
                        typeof ( FastShadow ),
                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (
                                Color.FromArgb ( 0x71, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 ),
                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );

        /// <summary>
        /// The Color property defines the Color used to fill the shadow region. 
        /// </summary> 
        [Category ( "Common Properties" )]
        public Color Color
        {
            get { return ( Color ) GetValue ( ColorProperty ); }
            set { SetValue ( ColorProperty, value ); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Distance from centre, why MS don't call this "distance" beats
        /// me.. Kept same as other Effects for consistency.
        /// </summary>
        [Category ( "Common Properties" ), Description ( "Distance from centre" )]
        public double ShadowDepth
        {
            get { return ( double ) GetValue ( ShadowDepthProperty ); }
            set { SetValue ( ShadowDepthProperty, value ); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShadowDepth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShadowDepthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register ( "ShadowDepth", typeof ( double ), typeof ( FastShadow ),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (
                5.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback ( ( o, e ) =>
                    {
                        FastShadow f = o as FastShadow;
                        if ( ( double ) e.NewValue < 0 )
                            f.ShadowDepth = 0;
                    } ) ) );


        /// <summary>
        /// Size of the shadow
        /// </summary>
        [Category ( "Common Properties" ), Description ( "Size of the drop shadow" )]
        public double BlurRadius
        {
            get { return ( double ) GetValue ( BlurRadiusProperty ); }
            set { SetValue ( BlurRadiusProperty, value ); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BlurRadius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BlurRadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register ( "BlurRadius", typeof ( double ), typeof ( FastShadow ),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( 10.0,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback ( ( o, e ) =>
                    {
                        FastShadow f = o as FastShadow;
                        if ( ( double ) e.NewValue < 0 )
                            f.BlurRadius = 0;
                    } ) ) );


        /// <summary>
        /// Angle of the shadow
        /// </summary>
        [Category ( "Common Properties" ), Description ( "Angle of the shadow" )]
        public int Direction
        {
            get { return ( int ) GetValue ( DirectionProperty ); }
            set { SetValue ( DirectionProperty, value ); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Direction.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register ( "Direction", typeof ( int ), typeof ( FastShadow ),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( 315, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );


        #endregion Dynamic Properties

        #region Protected Methods

        protected override void OnRender ( DrawingContext drawingContext )
        {

            double distance = Math.Max ( 0, ShadowDepth );
            double blurRadius = Math.Max ( BlurRadius, 0 );
            double angle = Direction + 45; // Make it behave the same as DropShadowEffect

            Rect shadowBounds = new Rect ( new Point ( 0, 0 ),
                             new Size ( RenderSize.Width, RenderSize.Height ) );

            shadowBounds.Inflate ( blurRadius, blurRadius );

            Color color = Color;

            // Transform angle for "Direction"
            double angleRad = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
            double xDispl = distance;
            double yDispl = distance;
            double newX = xDispl * Math.Cos ( angleRad ) - yDispl * Math.Sin ( angleRad );
            double newY = yDispl * Math.Cos ( angleRad ) + xDispl * Math.Sin ( angleRad );

            TranslateTransform translate = new TranslateTransform ( newX, newY );
            Rect transformed = translate.TransformBounds ( shadowBounds );

            // Hint: you can make the blur radius consume more "centre"
            //       region of the bounding box by doubling this here
            // blurRadius = blurRadius * 2;

            // Build a set of rectangles for the shadow box
            Rect [ ] edges = new Rect [ ] {
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.X,transformed.Y), new Size(blurRadius,blurRadius)), // TL
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.X+blurRadius,transformed.Y), new Size(Math.Max(transformed.Width-(blurRadius*2),0),blurRadius)), // T
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.Right-blurRadius,transformed.Y), new Size(blurRadius,blurRadius)), // TR
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.Right-blurRadius,transformed.Y+blurRadius), new Size(blurRadius,Math.Max(transformed.Height-(blurRadius*2),0))), // R
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.Right-blurRadius,transformed.Bottom-blurRadius), new Size(blurRadius,blurRadius)), // BR
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.X+blurRadius,transformed.Bottom-blurRadius), new Size(Math.Max(transformed.Width-(blurRadius*2),0),blurRadius)), // B
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.X,transformed.Bottom-blurRadius), new Size(blurRadius,blurRadius)), // BL
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.X,transformed.Y+blurRadius), new Size(blurRadius,Math.Max(transformed.Height-(blurRadius*2),0))), // L
                new Rect(new Point(transformed.X+blurRadius,transformed.Y+blurRadius), new Size(Math.Max(transformed.Width-(blurRadius*2),0),Math.Max(transformed.Height-(blurRadius*2),0))), // C
            };

            // Gradient stops look a lot prettier than
            // a perfectly linear gradient..
            GradientStopCollection gsc = new GradientStopCollection ( );
            Color stopColor = color;
            stopColor.A = ( byte ) ( color.A );
            gsc.Add ( new GradientStop ( color, 0.0 ) );
            stopColor.A = ( byte ) ( .74336 * color.A );
            gsc.Add ( new GradientStop ( stopColor, 0.1 ) );
            stopColor.A = ( byte ) ( .38053 * color.A );
            gsc.Add ( new GradientStop ( stopColor, 0.3 ) );
            stopColor.A = ( byte ) ( .12389 * color.A );
            gsc.Add ( new GradientStop ( stopColor, 0.5 ) );
            stopColor.A = ( byte ) ( .02654 * color.A );
            gsc.Add ( new GradientStop ( stopColor, 0.7 ) );
            stopColor.A = ( byte ) ( 0 );
            gsc.Add ( new GradientStop ( stopColor, 0.9 ) );

            gsc.Freeze ( );

            Brush [ ] colors = new Brush [ ]{
                // TL
                new RadialGradientBrush(gsc){ Center = new Point(1, 1), GradientOrigin = new Point(1, 1), RadiusX=1, RadiusY=1},
                // T
                new LinearGradientBrush(gsc, 0){ StartPoint = new Point(0,1), EndPoint=new Point(0,0)},
                // TR
                new RadialGradientBrush(gsc){ Center = new Point(0, 1), GradientOrigin = new Point(0, 1), RadiusX=1, RadiusY=1},
                // R
                new LinearGradientBrush(gsc, 0){ StartPoint = new Point(0,0), EndPoint=new Point(1,0)},
                // BR
                new RadialGradientBrush(gsc){ Center = new Point(0, 0), GradientOrigin = new Point(0, 0), RadiusX=1, RadiusY=1},
                // B
                new LinearGradientBrush(gsc, 0){ StartPoint = new Point(0,0), EndPoint=new Point(0,1)},
                // BL
                new RadialGradientBrush(gsc){ Center = new Point(1, 0), GradientOrigin = new Point(1, 0), RadiusX=1, RadiusY=1},
                // L
                new LinearGradientBrush(gsc, 0){ StartPoint = new Point(1,0), EndPoint=new Point(0,0)},
                // C
                new SolidColorBrush(color),
            };

            // This is a test pattern, uncomment to see how I'm drawing this
            //Brush[] colors = new Brush[]{
            //    Brushes.Red,
            //    Brushes.Green,
            //    Brushes.Blue,
            //    Brushes.Fuchsia,
            //    Brushes.Gainsboro,
            //    Brushes.LimeGreen,
            //    Brushes.Navy,
            //    Brushes.Orange,
            //    Brushes.White,
            //};
            double [ ] guidelineSetX = new double [ ] { transformed.X,
                                                    transformed.X+blurRadius,
                                                    transformed.Right-blurRadius,
                                                    transformed.Right};

            double [ ] guidelineSetY = new double [ ] { transformed.Y,
                                                    transformed.Y+blurRadius,
                                                    transformed.Bottom-blurRadius,
                                                    transformed.Bottom};

            drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet ( new GuidelineSet ( guidelineSetX, guidelineSetY ) );
            for ( int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i++ )
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle ( colors [ i ], null, edges [ i ], 0.0, 0.0 );
            }
            drawingContext.Pop ( );
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried raising the z-index?  <Grid Height="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Panel.ZIndex="10" > [...] </Grid>

Comment: Effects apply to anything within whatever you apply them to. Apply it to a container and any controls in it will get the effect.. you posted so much I can't see where your effect is. But the way to go is apply the effect to something else like a rectangle that fills the space you want the effect on but doesn't contain things.

Comment: @T.Schwarz: thx, i just tried it, it still looks the same. The glow appears on top of the rectangles.

Comment: @Andy: thx but my rectangles are outside the container the effects are applied to. That's why I don't understand why it doesn't appear on top of the effect being applied.

Comment: I think you confused decoration and effects.
Decorating is based on the Decorator class.
And it sits in the AdornerLayer above all content elements.
And the effects are the visual component of the element itself.
They are created based on the Effect class.
Effects are assigned to the UIElement.Effect property.

Comment: Render happens after measure+arrange, so it will render anywhere on the surface (unless clipped). If you render outside an element's box, you'll draw on other elements. You should *compose* your elements (overriding OnRender with WPF is almost always a bad smell) differently, use Effect or BitmapEffect (deprecated, slower because it doesn't use GPU but easier then writing a pixel shader) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Decorating is based on the Decorator class. And it sits in the AdornerLayer above all content elements.

Change the base class for FastShadow: use Effect (or a derivative from it) instead of Decorator.
Assign an instance of the FastShadow class to the Effect property.

Comment: Thx, can you give a small sample for the second part pls? Also will changing the deriving type to Effect have any performance cost? Because it's not my code, it's from here. And the guy was claiming it's faster than DropShadowEffect by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Decorator is, of course, much faster because it lacks any logic and largely ignores the layout.
If you want to leave the Decorator, then the logic of its rendering must take into account the real layout of the underlying elements.

Comment: I can't help with the example code yet - I don't have enough free time.
Perhaps tomorrow or the day after tomorrow there will be more time and I can do it.

Comment: I more took a closer look at the FastShadow code.
In its OnRender method, you are drawing outside of the element itself.
This is understandable since you want to get radiance.
But it is not clear to me how you would like this radiance to affect other elements.
Can you somehow demonstrate in the figure what effect you want to get?

Comment: thx, so yes I want the effect to be a glow but I want to draw a rectangle shape on top that's not affected by the effect just like a new Photoshop layer that's on top of the glow effect. I use rectangle for another purpose so it's not part of the glow effect. If I place the rectangle under the glow I would expect it to be affected by the glow effect, but not if it's on top of the glow effect.

Comment: For simplicity, let's just consider one Border with shine - no DataGrid and Templates.
Let it be located in the center of a Grid of three columns and three rows.
You make the glow fill the adjacent cells.
You create the glow in OnRender, so it is drawn AFTER all the elements are laid out (i.e. above them).
Now you add a small Rectangle to the top left cell.
How should it interact with the glow?

Comment: If it is to be positioned ABOVE the glow, then the glow must be part of the layout.
Therefore, it will not work in principle to draw a glow in the OnRender method, because when this method is called, there is no sufficient information about other UI elements.
For the effect you want, you actually need to create not a glow around the Border, but a background fill in the main Grid.
Then other children will be displayed on top of this fill.

Comment: But can the glow be drawn outside the grid? Because the glow radiates outward from the cell, it will bleed out outside the visible bounds of the cell.

Comment: I am writing about the same to you.
If you need to consider the layout of other elements and want to rely on WPF's automatic tools to do so, then the glow should be part of that layout.
That is, your glow should be a regular UI element with borders according to the provided layout.

If you want to draw a glow outside the borders with elements, then WPF's automatic tools won't be able to handle that.
This means that in the method for drawing a glow, you yourself need to check what neighboring elements are, and not make a glow over them.

Comment: Take a closer look yourself at the layout you create.
Your glow spreads throughout your environment.
And the elements that it should not light up are located not even in this DataGrid row.
Expand the Visual tree and you will see that their common ancestor is only ItemsPanel.
Therefore, to take into account the layout of the elements, you will have to draw this glow on the background of this panel.

Comment: To make it easier for you to understand better, create a simplified solution without DataGrid and templates.
Create a regular StackPanel and in it several (2-3) Grid, each of which has the elements you need (some of them with a glow).
And see how elements from different Grid will interact with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've noticed (or if it's intentional), but the "glow" only affects higher up rows, and not rows further down. It's too subtle to see in your screenshot, but it becomes clear if you increase the intensity of the glow effect. For example the "coin" on row 7 results in a glow that overlaps the two or three rows above, but the glow doesn't appear at all in row 8 or below. This seems to have something to do with each successive row having a higher z-index than the last, so row 8 gets renders over the already-rendered glow effect, so is another reason why your current solution may be difficult to resolve!

I suspect the datagrid's odd visual tree is going to prevent you from achieving what you want with your current solution: you can't have a glow effect that renders across multiple grid rows *and* appears behind the rows' content (the green & blue rectangles), so you might need to approach this from a different angle. While I don't have a concrete solution to this, I would suggest investigating a way to draw the glow effects on a layer *behind* the datagrid (e.g. using a canvas).

This means the data grid rows would need to have a transparent b/g colour of course, so you might need to rethink how you achieve the alternating row colours.

When you add a glow effect to the canvas (which could be as simple as a Border control with a linear gradient b/g), you'll need to know where to place it (i.e. Canvas.Top) to ensure it appears behind the correct datagrid row. If all rows have the same fixed height then this should be a trivial calculation.

The canvas would have to scroll "in sync" with the datagrid, as the user scrolls the latter, ensuring that the glow effects (Border controls) on the canvas remain in place behind their respective rows. I think you'd need to place the canvas inside a ScrollViewer, then manipulate its scroll position from within scroll event handlers on the datagrid. You may find other SO articles detailing how to detect scrolling (and by how much).

It goes without saying that you'd have to do all this in code-behind, not with XAML alone!

Comment: Thanks yes I am aware of this issue, I created a question about it but no reply. What you are suggesting sounds like it will be a lot of work but also likely be performance hit, then I imagine my best bet is to just use a regular dropshadow which doesnt have this issue AFAIK.